# Using printf function in the assembler code

Tags: windows, assembly

I'd like to call `printf` function twice in assembler code like that:

```
PUSH     word ptr [sstr1]
CALL     _printf
ADD      ESP,0x4
PUSH     word ptr [sstr2]
CALL     _printf
ADD      ESP,0x4
JMP      _main::go_back
```

But the code makes print only the fist string...

Comment: Trace your code in a debugger, check that both printf calls are executed and the strings pushed are pointing to correct locations.

Comment: `push word ptr [mem]` only decrements ESP by 2.  Either that or `add esp,4` is wrong, depending on the pointer width in your system.  (Almost always, pointers will be the same width as the minimum "stack slot" functions are expecting for arg passing.)